# Emacs hangs in haskell-mode with inferior-haskell-load-file call

Tags: haskell, emacs

When in a Haskell file, I use `C-c C-l` to run the command `inferior-haskell-load-file` which is intended to load the current file into the GHCI interpreter but Emacs just hangs until I hit `C-g`. Anyone know how I can get this to work?

GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.5) of 2011-08-14 on allspice, modified by Debian

Using haskell-mode version v2.7.0

Comment: Do you have a customised `.ghci` file?  That might interfere, especially if you change the prompt...  Otherwise, do you have a problem if you launch with "emacs -Q" and then explicitly load just the defaults?

Comment: @ivanm that was it! Add it as the answer please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

inferior-haskell-mode does some parsing based upon the expected ghci prompt.  As such, if you change the prompt in a `.ghci` file, then it can't detect it.

For more information, see where [haskell-ghci.el](http://code.haskell.org/haskellmode-emacs/haskell-ghci.el) sets the `comint-prompt-regexp` value to determine what a prompt *is*.

```
;; GHCi prompt should be of the form `ModuleName> '.
(setq comint-prompt-regexp
      "^\\*?[[:upper:]][\\._[:alnum:]]*\\( \\*?[[:upper:]][\\._[:alnum:]]*\\)*> ")
```

If you want to keep the setting in your `.ghci` file, then it may be possible to customise this settings.

Comment: Great tip. Thanks so much. You've saved me a ton of headache.

Comment: Many of us have this in .ghci: `:set prompt "λ> "`.  It would be nice to include λ by default in the pattern.

Comment: I'm out of luck trying to modify the regexp in order to accept "λ> ". This must be some regexp non-ascii issue...

Comment: @gawi: if you use Christopher Done's stuff that's currently in github then it uses λ> as the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but as I just ran into this today, I wanted to share how to actually customize  `comint-prompt-regexp` since I had to figure it out.

This customization will recognize `λ>` prompts, or actually any single character before `>`), but it doesn't break the existing regex. In your `.emacs`:

```
(load-library "inf-haskell")

(defun my-inf-haskell-hook ()
  (setq comint-prompt-regexp 
        (concat comint-prompt-regexp "\\|^.> ")))

(add-to-list 'inferior-haskell-mode-hook 'my-inf-haskell-hook)
```

You can add more dots to `"\\|^.> "` to recognize a longer prompt, but I wanted to keep it fixed-length for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem caused by GHCi reporting some kind of error on startup, causing the Emacs haskell mode to wait for the GHCi prompt indefinitely (GHCi didn't show the standard prompt (`Prelude>`), but rather just showed `>`). You can try running GHCi externally and see if it reports any errors.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's reporting any errors. What kind of errors and where do you specifically mean?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message when I tried to use stack with emacs.  For me, adding this line to my .emacs/init.el resolved the problem:

```
(setq haskell-program-name "stack ghci")
```