# ghci: Custom Prompt in Emacs haskell-mode

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghci

How do you set up a custom prompt in ghci so that it works properly with inferior haskell process ?

I know that I can modify ~/.ghci, but that leads to another  [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961786/emacs-hangs-in-haskell-mode-with-inferior-haskell-load-file-call).

Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following thing pattern matches in the latest haskell-mode:

```
:set prompt "λ> "
```